# Can a master-detail relationship be blank?

Tags: custom-object, relationships, master-detail

I have an object: `objectA__c`, with 2 master-detail relationships, one to `objectB__c` and one to `objectC__c` is it possible to leave one of these relatonships blank?

I would like `objectA__c` to always have a relationship to `objectB__c` but it's relationship to `objectC__c` should be optional.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Master-Detail` fields are a special kind of required fields, it has special considerations beyond just whether a value is required or not. When you set up a child as a master-detail, you're saying that it's tightly coupled to the Parent record; it cannot exist without a parent. Children in a Master Detail inherit security from their parent, they inherit their owner from the parent, they will be deleted when the parent is deleted, etc.

For these reasons, the only way a child table can be tied to a parent table with a Master Detail is for every record of the child to have a relationship to some parent.

> Instead of Master Detail you can create a lookup relationship if you
>   want the column to be optional.